# Sensitivity Measures for GEE Model

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations, sensitivity-analysis, cooks-distance, leverage

Is there any method (e.g. like Cooks D) implemented in R to identify leverage points for GEE Models? I used geepack to fit my models and would like to do a sensitivity analysis now. However, I don't seem to find any R package that has any kind of leverage measure implemented?

Comment: Hi there. *1)* Which sensitivity analyses would you like to perform? *2)* Why not code it yourself? – *Reviewer*